# Can $f(x) = \sqrt{x_1 x_2} + \sqrt{x_3 x_4}$ be solved by Kuhn–Tucker conditions?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider

$\max_{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4} f(x) = \sqrt{x_1 x_2} + \sqrt{x_3 x_4}$

s.t. $\; p_1x_1 + p_2x_2 + p_3x_3 + p_4x_4 \le w$

I know we can solve the max problem through separately considering case(i): $x_1, x_2 > 0$ and $x_3 = x_4 = 0$; and case (ii) $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ and $x_3, x_4 > 0$.

But is it possible to solve the whole optimization problem through the Kuhn–Tucker method?

We can write down the Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda)=\sqrt{x_1x_2}+\sqrt{x_3x_4}+\lambda(w-p_1x_1-p_2x_2-p_3x_3-p_4x_4)$

with the complementary slackness conditions (for choice variables):

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x_2}{x_1}}-\lambda p_1 \le 0,\quad x_1 \ge 0, \quad \text{and}\quad  x_1 \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=0$.

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x_1}{x_2}}-\lambda p_2 \le 0,\quad x_2 \ge 0, \quad \text{and}\quad  x_2 \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=0$.

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_3}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x_4}{x_3}}-\lambda p_3 \le 0,\quad x_3 \ge 0, \quad \text{and}\quad  x_3 \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_3}=0$.

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_4}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x_3}{x_4}}-\lambda p_4 \le 0,\quad x_4 \ge 0, \quad \text{and}\quad  x_4 \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_4}=0$.

However, when guessing say, $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2,x_3,x_4>0$, $\lim_{x_1 \to 0}\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} \to \infty$, which does not satisfy the complementary slackness $x_1 \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} = 0$.

I do not whether we can use the Kuhn–Tucker method to solve this optimization problem? And if not, what are the reasons?